# Comparative without "than", or with "as opposed to" instead of "than"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Can we use a comparative without "than", or substitute "as opposed to" for "than" in the following sentence:

> Beef is tastier as opposed to game meat.

Is the sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example from the question:

> Beef is tastier as opposed to game meat.

is not something that a fluent speaker would say or write. The most obvious way to express what I take to be the meaning would be:

> Beef is tastier than game meat.

That is a straightforward comparison, and is grammatically valid and quite natural.

The phrase "as opposed to" is not normally preceded by a comparative adjective.  One might use this phrase in a sentence such as:

> Beef, as opposed to game meat, is quite tasty.

The more general form is

> X, as opposed to Y, is Z.

X and Y will both be nouns or noun phrases, and Z will be a property that either X or Y might have or might lack. This says that "X is Z but Y is not Z".